# running dotnet docker container with docker-compose

Tags: .net-core, docker-compose

I have gone through the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/) but running across issues as I'm launching the containers through docker-compose.

I'm using docker-compose because I have more than one containers that directly correlates to each csproj file within the location, also the docs refer to attributes using Dockerfile which itself adds another layer of complexity.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services: 

  app1:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
    container_name: app1
    restart: on-failure
    working_dir: /service
    command: bash -c "dotnet build && dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/App1.dll"
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - "./App1:/service"

  app2:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2
    container_name: app2
    restart: on-failure
    working_dir: /service
    command: bash -c "dotnet build && dotnet bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/App2.dll"
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
      - 5000:500
```

**Project Structure**

```
Microservice.sln
    App1/App1.csproj
    App2/App2.csproj
```

**Issue**

My IDE starts to complain as soon as I run the containers for all kinds of syntax errors, and a local build simply fails.

is there a way to be able to compile the app locally as well as in the docker?

**Edit**

[image]

[image]

Comment: what errors are you getting..?

Comment: attached two images, it just loses package references, to resolve, i stop the container, go to root of the project and execute `dotnet build` or `dotnet restore` and everything is back to normal.